# Xamarin SQLite LINQ query always returns a list of 0 values

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have a table `TableMasterFields` with a fields `IdAddressSet` and `PropertyCategory`.

I am using SQLIte in a Xamarin. project.

When I form the query

```
 var lst = (from objTableMasterFields in sqliteConnection.Table<TableMasterFields>()
            where objTableMasterFields.IdAddressSet == idAddressSet
               && objTableMasterFields.PropertyCategory != 0
            select objTableMasterFields);
```

The list contains 32 entries with the correct data. The `objTableMasterFields.PropertyCategory` fields have values between 1 and 9.

Now I want to transform the list, because I need only the unique `PropertyCategory` values.

```
 var lst = (from objTableMasterFields in sqliteConnection.Table<TableMasterFields>()
            where objTableMasterFields.IdAddressSet == idAddressSet
               && objTableMasterFields.PropertyCategory != 0
            select objTableMasterFields.PropertyCategory).Distinct().ToList<int>();
```

Now I get a lst with exact 1 integer entry with the value 0!

Using

```
 var lst = (from objTableMasterFields in sqliteConnection.Table<TableMasterFields>()
            where objTableMasterFields.IdAddressSet == idAddressSet
               && objTableMasterFields.PropertyCategory != 0
            select objTableMasterFields.PropertyCategory).ToList<int>();
```

I get a list of 32 integer entries with the value 0.

Were is my fault?

I am using VS-2017 15.5.2!

This is my current workarround:

```
var data = (from objTableMasterFields in sqliteConnection.Table<TableMasterFields>()
            where objTableMasterFields.IdAddressSet == idAddressSet
               && objTableMasterFields.PropertyCategory != 0
            select objTableMasterFields);
Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var entry in data)
    dic.TryAdd(entry.PropertyCategory,0);
return dic.Keys.ToList<int>();
```

**EDIT**

This doesn't work too:

```
var lst = (from objTableMasterFields in sqliteConnection.Table<TableMasterFields>()
           where objTableMasterFields.IdAddressSet == idAddressSet
              && objTableMasterFields.PropertyCategory != 0
           select objTableMasterFields).Select(o => o.PropertyCategory)
```

Comment: I think you need to use SelectMany to flatten your list

Comment: Why and where should SelectMany help? If have already a flat list.